# Tension force transmitted to 4 attachment points

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, statics

I have a given 3D vector of tension force ($\vec{T}$) and I want to find a way to transmit it through 4 strings that connect the attachment points $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}, \vec{d}$, whose values are known.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction here or given me any reference?

Comment: Is it through time or just finding the initial acceleration and tensions at $t=0,~ \vec{x}=0,~ \vec{v}=0, ~ \vec{a} \neq 0, ~ \vec{\alpha} \neq 0$ And is there gravity

Comment: What do you mean “find a way to transmit it”? You mean calculate the four string tensions right with given string lengths?

Comment: I mean calculate the tension forces on the four strings. The natural length of each string is known.

Comment: Well if you cant bother to read a couple sentences and answer I certainly wont take the time to write up and answer

Answer (score 0):

For the point where the strings come together, you can write force component equations for each of three orthogonal directions.  But, you are looking for four unknown tensions. Unless someone is seeing a relationship that I don't see, I don't think there is a unique answer.  If the upper tension is leaning more toward one of the lower strings, you might assume that the tension in that one is zero, and then solve for the other three.

Comment: Mr. Bird, I agree.  3 points define a plane, and the OP is using 4 points on the plane given in his problem.  This makes the problem over-specified.

Comment: I dont think the object is in stasis. There is a given force vector on the system. And it isnt vertical. I think there might be a unique soln. The tensions must match the F=ma and T=I $\omega$

Comment: And.. now he wrote “the natural length of each string is known” making me think maybe they are not strings as normally defined in such problems but equivalent of lobg springs with high k’s. If so it has a dynamical soln. Whether it could be solved analytically is different question. @DavidWhite too